# Logging out a specific user with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am in the process of adding password reset functionality to a Flask web app.

When a password is reset I'd like to log out anyone who was logged in with that username. I am aware of the `logout_user()` method supplied by Flask-Login. In my application the password reset is done while the user is not logged in - using email confirmation. It is basically "Forgot my password" functionality. I'm looking for something like `logout_user(specific_user)`. Or a way of invalidating a specific users cookies? Something along these lines.

I'd like to do this because currently if a users credentials get stolen and they reset their password, the person with the stolen credentials is still logged in and has access to the web app.

Comment: _"I'd like to do this because currently if a users credentials get stolen and they reset their password, the person with the stolen credentials is still logged in and has access to the web app."_ - What do you mean **exactly** when you say "credentials", because if its the username & password, then logging a user out is not going to help with this situation.

Comment: The credentials are as you have mentioned. The app first sends a confirmation email to the user asking them to confirm they want to reset their password. If they click the confirm link in the email a new password is generated and send to their email. A user who does not have access to this email address will not know this new password. If they can be forcefully logged out then they wont be able to log back in.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: sure it will; if the password *also* changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably store the timestamp of the password reset and compare it to the user cookie. If the password has been reset after the cookie has been generated, you ask the user to provide login/password again.

Flask-Login cookie does not contain a timestamp by default, hence you will have to tweak that a little bit.

It would probably be worth posting an issue on Flask-Login's GitHub because it seems to be a standard use case.

**EDIT:** There's actually a better way to do that, see https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#alternative-tokens. It's about using the user password hash (among other things) to sign the "Remember Me" cookie. This way if the password changes the cookie is de facto unvalidated.

Comment: What I did was follow the steps outlined in the docs; set up the `token_loader` callback function on my `LoginManager` object and created a `get_auth_token` function in my `User` class.

The trick for me seemed to be - I haven't thoroughly tested this - setting `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME=0` in the app config. It seems that the "Remember Me" cookie is only looked at by Flask-Login when the users session has expired. Currently I am using a 5 min session lifetime because of the additional overhead required to encode and decode the "Remember Me" token on each request.

Comment: One issue I can foresee with my solution is that a logged in user, running an invalid session because of a password change, could refresh the page (make a request) every 4min in order to keep their session alive.